# Roots of continuous function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Suppose $\varphi : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function. Are the roots of $\varphi$ necessarily discrete?

I'm aware that the roots of a holomorphic function are discrete, but I cannot find a reference for continuous functions.

Comment: No. $\varphi(z)=0$ is a continuous function, and so is $\varphi(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z)\,$ for example.

Comment: 'Zeros' would be more appropriate than 'roots', I suppose. I may be wrong, but I think 'roots' associate mainly with polynomials, not with arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 11):

No. For a continuous function $\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}f:\C\to\C$ any closed subset
of $\C$ can occur as its zero set. If $A\subseteq \C$ is closed, define
$f(z)=\inf\{|z-a|:a\in A\}$. Then $f$ is continuous (and real-valued)
and its zero set is $A$.

Comment: I know that I'm being fussy right now, but the case $A = \varnothing$ has to be considered separately with e.g. $f \equiv 1$.

Comment: @Adayah there is no need for a separate case; it'd suffice to add $1$ to the set over which the infimum is taken.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one? $$z\mapsto z\sin|z|$$ Seems to be zero at every circle of radius $n\pi\ (n\in\mathbb N)$ centered at the Argand's plane's origin.